# How do I render API image data in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image

I'm new to coding and I'm working on this for a project and need some direction. I tried looking online for my answer but they all seem to be written differently or API functions differently, etc. For my project, the user sets parameters in order to render an background image with an emoji. Currently I'm working on the background image portion and I don't know how to proceed. My issue is after they plug in the parameters, it finishes the link and accesses the API (phpnoise). I have it record in the console the response which gives me a series of data:

> {type: 'cors', url: 'https://php-noise.com/noise.php?r=15&g=15&b=15&tiles=15&tileSize=15&json', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}body: (...)bodyUsed: trueheaders: Headers {}ok: trueredirected: falsestatus: 200statusText: "OK"type: "cors"url: "https://php-noise.com/noise.php?r=15&g=15&b=15&tiles=15&tileSize=15&json"[[Prototype]]: Response

Woohoo! but the thing is I don't know how to proceed from here. If I access the link in my browser it supplies me with:

> {
> "uri": "https://php-noise.com/images/noise_r15-g15-b15-t15-tS15-bW0-mB-mu1.5-st5_e6054205e2a73c137a3222bb29ef011d.png"
> }

Which is the result generated and the image I wish to actually supply to the container on my page. Can someone help me to figure out how I get this to display in an HTML element? This is my code so far:

```
var genButton = $("#genBtn");
var image = $("#imageResults")
var tiles = $('#parameter1');
var tileSize = $('#parameter2');
var genResults = $('#genResults');
var red = $('#parameter3');
var blue = $('#parameter4');
var green = $('#parameter5');
var numTiles = $('#parameter1');
var tSize = $('#parameter2');

genButton.on('click', getApi);

function getApi(event) {
 event.preventDefault()
  var r = red.val();
  var b = blue.val();
  var g = green.val();
  var tiles = numTiles.val();
  var tileSize = tSize.val();
  var backgroundApi = `https://php-noise.com/noise.php?r=${r}&g=${g}&b=${b}&tiles=${tiles}&tileSize=${tileSize}&json`;
  
  
  
  fetch(backgroundApi)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.status)
    console.log(response)
    return response.json();
  })
  .then
  genResults.textContent=backgroundApi.uri
  
  
  getEmojiApi();
  generateParameters();
};
```

And this is the part of the HTML where i'm looking to render the image:

```
               <!-- Image Container -->
                <div class="column is-flex is-flex-direction-column is-align-items-center">
                    <div id="genResults">
                        <img id="imageResults">
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the URL to set the `src` attribute of the `<img>` element. This is how:

In your JavaScript:

```
fetch(backgroundApi)
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.status);
    return response.json();
  })
.then(function (data) {
    // Assuming data.uri contains the image URL
    var imageResults = document.getElementById('imageResults');
    imageResults.src = data.uri;
  })
.catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
getEmojiApi();
generateParameters();
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Thank you very much!